# Stripe webhook response times

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, webhooks

When a customer pays, the following entry is stored into the database:

```
DB::table('subscriptions')->insert([
    'user_id' => $user->id,
    'quantity' => 1,
    'stripe_id' => $request->paymentIntent,
    'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
]);
```

The record is saved successfully. When listening to the Stripe webhook `payment_intent.succeeded` I want to grab the paymentIntent Id from the webhook and find the record in my database:

```
$paymentInstance = DB::table('subscriptions')->where('stripe_id',$paymentIntent->id)->first();
```

The variable `$paymentIntent` is initialised directly within the webhook:

```
$event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
    $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
);
...
switch ($event->type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        $paymentIntent = $event->data->object;
        // Usage of $paymentIntent->id....
```

The first call responds with `null` (echo $paymentInstance). When I hit resend in the Stripe dashboard, I get the desired result. **How is this possible?** The storing of the initial record has to be faster then the webhook reaching the server for the first time – or am I mistaken?

Comment: How is the variable `$paymentIntent` being initialized?

Comment: It's definitely possible for the event to reach you before your code is done running and saving the payment intent id after its creation.

Comment: @levi I updated my question with this missing bit.

Comment: @koopajah That really should not happen. If the first call was successfull, then there won't be a second or even third attempt and I won't be able to handle the response accordingly.

Comment: @Andreas , as @koopajah states, it's really hard to tell what cause the problem and definitely possible somewhere was interrupted. My suggestion is that whatever additional data you want to send to your database, you can add those data into `stripe request body` in your frontend. So you can retrieve from `$paymentIntent`.